# Get something inside a tag with preg match all php

Tags: php, html

I have this HTML:

```
<a href="somelink;ref=start" class="head-title">APRILIA Tuono V4 1100 Factory, 175 PS</a>
```

It is possible to get the text between: `class="head-title">` and `</a>` in `preg_match_all`?

Comment: Your output should be `class="head-title"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to get the text `APRILIA Tuono V4 1100 Factory, 175 PS` from your example string above then this expression will work

```
^[^>]+>([^<]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Xnt0Ls/1

Answer (score 1):

You should [not use regular expressions for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), as it will very likely break when your HTML input gets more complicated.

Use the DOM parser that PHP provides:

```
function getNodeText($html, $classname) {
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $finder = new DomXPath($dom);
    $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
    return $nodes[0]->textContent;
}

$html = '<a href="somelink;ref=start" class="head-title">APRILIA Tuono V4 1100 Factory, 175 PS</a>';
$classname="head-title";
echo getNodeText($html, $classname); // APRILIA Tuono V4 1100 Factory, 175 PS
```

Comment: I like to answer OP's questions using the tools and parameters that are asked for.

Comment: I like to avoid repeating wrong practices and point the Asker to best practices. We all differ.